# Worker JS catch OPTION

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, service-worker

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  // Handling logic for other request methods (GET, POST, etc.)
  // ...

  if (event.request.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    // How can I capture OPTION requests here?
    // I want to perform some additional processing.
  }
});
```

I have implemented a JavaScript Worker in my project to intercept and handle various HTTP requests. However, it seems that my worker is successfully intercepting all requests except for the OPTION request method. I would like to know how I can capture the OPTION requests as well. Here's a simplified version of my current code: